# Navigation Property Not Loading in the Poco's

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, .net-4.5

i'm using SQLite Provider with Entity Frame work in .Net 4.5

```
        conferControlEntities.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        conferControlEntities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        conferControlEntities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
        conferControlEntities.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
```

and i am also using inheritance in the Entity Framework

so i cannot use the include in the query as i can't include the derived objects navigation property

so i have fillNavigationPropty method in Poco classes which will make a call to the Navigation properties and try to fill them

but whenever i check it will be null

```
            using (var context = GetContext(false,true))
            {
                var queryable = context.Delegates.Where(i => i.ParentId == id);
                foreach (var entity in queryable)
                {
                    entity.FillNavigationProperties();
                    list.Add(WrapperFactory.Create(entity) as TU);
                }
                return new ObservableCollection<TU>(list);
            }
```

POCO Example

```
public class TempPOCO
{
      public virtual AnotherPCOCCLassTYpe NavigationProperty1{get;set;}
      public void FillNavigationProperties()
      {
            var tempcall = NavigationProperty1;
      }
}
```

Comment: Are your navigation properties defined virtual? Could you post one of your poco classes?

Comment: yes all the navigation properties are defined as virtual

Comment: Then please add one of your poco classes and the code of the entity.FillNavigationProperties() method to your question.

Comment: updated with the poco example

Comment: Hard to say, but try to check the following things. Are the properties filled when using eager loading. context.Delegates.Where(i => i.ParentId == id).Include(p => p.NavigationProperty1). Check if the Proxy type is really created (entity.GetType().Name == some name with a guid). Check if LazyLoading is realy activated on the context instance: db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled == true